# Chromebook VPN support

Tags: vpn, openvpn, google-chrome-os, pptp

Can a VPN be used in the Chrome OS? I have not been able to determine if a VPN can be used on the various models. I am looking for either pptp or openvpn support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a great tutorial directly from the google-support how to configure a VPN in Chrome OS.](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1282338?hl=en)

Chromebooks/Chrome os currently support the following VPNs:

- L2TP over IPsec with PSK
- L2TP over IPsec with certificate-based authentication
- OpenVPN

Below is a list of a few VPNs that are not currently supported.

- SSL VPN solutions
- Any VPN implementation other than L2TP over IPsec or OpenVPN